# Collection of all configurable products (which has children)

Tags: magento-1.9, script

What is the best way to Collection of all configurable products (which has children) with sku using script?

How to do that?

Comment: Please specify magento version. M1 or M2?

Comment: in magento1 and please create script so i have easily use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Try following code:**

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app();

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
    ->addFieldToFilter('type_id','configurable');

$data = array();
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')
                ->getUsedProducts(null, $product);
    if (count($childProducts)) {
        foreach($childProducts as $childProduct) {
            if (isset($data[$product->getSku()]) && $data[$product->getSku()]) {
                $data[$product->getSku()] .= " || ".$childProduct->getSku();
            } else {
                $data[$product->getSku()] = $childProduct->getSku();
            }
        }
    }
}

echo "<pre>";print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd());
$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
Mage::app();

$_productCollection1 = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id','configurable'); 

foreach ($_productCollection1 as $product1) {
    echo $product1->getName();
$childIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getChildrenIds($product1->getId());
 or 
 $childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getUsedProducts(null,$product1);
}
```

Please let me know if you have any query or question.